# Angular Button click rotate icon

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, font-awesome

I have the following button

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" (click)="executeUsecase(usecase.UsecaseId)"><i class="fa fa-play "></i></button>
```

it shows a play icon.

I want this play icon to spin when I click on this. How can i achieve it?

I am using typescript in angular 4

Comment: You have to use css with [ngClass]

Answer (score 10):

You can use CSS only for that, no Angular required :

```css
button:focus i {
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
```

Comment: You can focus a button without click on him.

Comment: button is not rotating...:(

Comment: Then you have an issue with your computer. Please make a [mcve] on stackblitz, I'll fork it and make it work for you.

Comment: That's a blank plunkr ... Create a [mcve], which means put your code in it, and use stackblitz (you'll see how much easier it is)

Comment: can  u put ur code there as make it work,,i will take from there

Comment: My code is already working in the snippet. If you want something applied to your case, make a [mcve]. Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: So if it works, that means either your code works, or you didn't use your code. So please, post your code, not mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a flag in your component as follows:

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
      [ngClass]="{'clicked': isClicked}" type="button"
      (click)="executeUsecase(usecase.UsecaseId)">>
      <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    </button>
  `
})
export class Component {
  ...
  isClicked: false;

  executeUsecase(id) {
    ...
    this.isClicked = true;
  }
}
```

css:

```
.btn {
  transition: all 2s ease-out !important;
}
.clicked {
  transform: rotate(20deg)
}
```

Comment: yes,, i put an alert its popup up in ts executeUsecase()

Comment: So if the class is correctly added, it means that you don't add the css code.