# Rotate an fa-icon element

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

i'm using  Font Awesome in my Angular application and i'm trying to rotate a refresh icon when it's clicked.

```html
<div class="col-5 d-flex justify-content-end"> 
   <span class="mr-4 pr-3">
      <fa-icon
         style="color: white; font-size: large; top: 0;"
         [icon]="faArrowAltCircleDown"
         (click)="refreshTaskList()">
      </fa-icon>
   </span>
</div>
```

I've tried to add `rotate="360"` aswell as `transform="rotate-90"` but unfortunately all without any success.

I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55091605/8620333

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS only for that, no Angular required:

```css
button:focus i {
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
```

You could use above code and convert it so it fulfills to your desired results.

*Source: [Angular Button click rotate icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983594/10878491)*

*Related question* ([Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)'s comment)*: [Font Awesome 5 How to arrange different icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090770/font-awesome-5-animated-cogs-how-to-arrange-different-icons/55091605#55091605)*

Comment: i need to use <fa-icon > and not <button > !!

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you could use the sample code I posted and convert it so it works for your desired outcome.
Please try and visit the source I posted on the bottom of my answer, I'm sure you'll get quite far.
Let me know when you're struggling again.